# Unable to create pg_graphql extension in RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-rds

I want to create pg_graphql extension in postgres rds database but i am facing below error.

> ERROR:  Could not open extension control file
> "/rdsdbbin/postgres-15.4.R3/share/extension/pg_graphql.control": No
> such file or directory.extension "pg_graphql" is not available ERROR:
> extension "pg_graphql" is not available SQL state: 0A000 Detail: Could
> not open extension control file
> "/rdsdbbin/postgres-15.4.R3/share/extension/pg_graphql.control": No
> such file or directory. Hint: The extension must first be installed on
> the system where PostgreSQL is running.

i am using 15.4 postgres rds version.

Comment: You can't.  It is not supported.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html#postgresql-extensions-15x

Comment: Please provide details on what you have tried to do to install and activate the extension.